# Climate Change--Revised

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Firstly, thanks to brianpck, Joonas, cnread & Quidam for their intervention and many helpful suggestions on the restructuring of this Q.

Climate change (CC)/ Global Warming (GW)--phrases that have entered the public lexicon. The Romans did not have to worry about these phenomena; they just had to survive wars, disease & dental problems. How would CC have been expressed in Latin?

Perhaps with an ablative absolute: "caelo mutante" = "with the climate changing"; using the gerund: "paratus ad mutandum" = "prepared for the changing"; "operam damus mutando" = "we pay attention to the changing".

The mass-planting of trees has been posited as a (partial) solution in the improvement of air quality. How would this be expressed in as few words, of Latin, as possible? (The chemistry/ biochemistry/ political inaction are beyond the scope of the Q.)

Perhaps, invoking Horace ("nunc est Bibendum" = "now one must drink"): "nunc est serendum" = "now one must plant"; "mox erit spirandum" = "soon one must/ will breathe"; the solving of the problem giving: "laetitia spirandi" = "the joy of breathing"; the nominative of the gerund (an infinitive verb): "serere est spirare" = "planting is breathing"; "arboribus satis spirare potuimus." = "with the trees having been planted we were able to breathe."

"Global Warming" can be translated in similar ways using verbs "tepefacere" = "to warm"; with reference to the polar ice-sheets; "liquefacere" = "to melt".

Any thoughts on the translations of CC/ GW?